# Loading REST Service in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

How do I load this REST service in QGIS?

https://tpwd.texas.gov/arcgis/rest/services/GIS/Ecosys1/MapServer

The ArcGIS REST API Connector returns the error:

```
[Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL
routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:Certificate:certificate verify failure
```

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS 2.16 you can add the Mapservice without a problem. (Using the built in functionality, not the plugin, that is.) Then you can ignore the certificate failure.

The core of the problem is a server side certificate problem. If it is not yours you can only notify the server owner.

---

Log:

- Unable To Get Local Issuer Certificate: The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found
- Certificate Untrusted: The root CA certificate is not trusted for this purpose

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372942/ssl-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate