# QGIS 2.14.4 certificate error after installation

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.14

When QGIS 2.14.4 is being deployed to a new PC, we get the following error message:

- Unable To Get Local Issuer Certificate: The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found
- Certificate Untrusted: The root CA certificate is not trusted for this purpose

[image]

How do we resolve this issue?

Comment: When exactly do you get this error? I guess when connecting to a (REST?) service? If this is the case the service owner needs to correct certificates. Looks like a certificate problem server side. Errorlog message is a known one. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203673/loading-rest-service-in-qgis/203681#203681 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372942/ssl-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate.

Comment: Possibly related to this bug: ~ https://issues.qgis.org/issues/13471

Answer (score 1):

The core of the problem is a server side certificate problem. If it is not yours you can only notify the server owner.

---

Log:

- Unable To Get Local Issuer Certificate: The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found
- Certificate Untrusted: The root CA certificate is not trusted for this purpose

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372942/ssl-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: In this case though it's not a self signed certificate (https://ubuntu.qgis.org/version.txt)